# AngularJS & PHP: upload my app on several servers after changes

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, git, deployment

I develop an **angular-php** web application which I have it running online, for different users, on 5 different subdomains, such us:

1. sub1.mydomain.com
2. sub2.mydomain.com
3. sub3.mydomain.com
4. sub4.mydomain.com
5. sub5.mydomain.com

**Problem:**

My problem is that I still develop the web-app local and whenever I change files(php, js,tpl.html,css or when add new ones) I have to upload them on each **subdomain**.

**Question:**
Is there a way/library/API whatever that I can use to make something like package (with the updated or new files) and just call it from each subdomain url , and make the appropriate updates?

Or should I just copy them to each subdomain?

Do I make myself clear, in other words just like on cms systems that we press the update button and we update a component/module.

If anyone knows a way of doing that please enlight me. Thanks.

I tried to depict what i mean.
[image]

Comment: do you have some kind of build tool like gulp/grunt? There are several deploy plugins for that

Comment: no , i just have bower which i use to install and update modules to my web-app. Should i look for those?

Answer (score 3):

What you are describing is called **deployment**.

There are a lot of ways to create a deployment mechanism so there is not a single answer to your question. Depends of the tools that you are using, the servers where your app is hosted, etc.

If not, I advise you to use Git to make versions of your app (with Github or Gitlab) and automate the deployment process when you push a new piece of code.

You can make your own scripts to deploy or use online services (surely what you need because of "systems that we press the update button").

I can't advice you one particular service but you would find what you need in Googling "deployment automation github".

Comment: Currently , i use git local on my pc where i have all the changes history, because github for private repositories costs. But anyway, you suggest to upload the web-app on the github and then comes all the rest, which is i suppose a github mechanism. So , i cant make a mechanism ,local, that gets all the changes , somehow? I will look for that you suggested to check it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it with config files. Considering the code for all my substations is the same. I would have config for each sub-domain and fetch the core files from the same location but serving different data If your structure allows it.